# Why do I need to wait for 90 minutes before posting a new question?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I am new to Stack Overflow and I am really thankful to all the people who have helped me here.

My problem is that I implement my whole code alone and I save the problems that I faced. Then I try to make a research to solve them all. I may solve some of them but I still need other people to help me in 2 or three things.

However, unfortunately, SO doesn't allow me to post a new question until I wait for 90 minutes after posting a question.

Why is that?

Comment: Why do you save up all of your questions and try to ask them all at once?

Comment: @CodyGray because while I am programming, I need to do many issues. I think it is better to focus on understanding my code rather than make other people give suggestions. then when I finish coding and finish researching, I wouldn't need a lot of help. Plus, I noticed that this approach is good because users try to give me their way to solve the problem, but I always ask about what the wrong is in my way.

Comment: A quote from the duplicate: *It's a bit unfortunate for those that do ask good questions right off the bat, and bless you if you're in that very small minority - it won't take long for you to establish yourself, perhaps just one question could do it.* Once you reach 125 reputation, the limit is removed.